# how to hook up web3 injected by metamask in angular 2

Tags: web3js, metamask, angular2

As described in metamask github, one can bootstrap metamask like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask) if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);   } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));   }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:   startApp()

})
```

How do I implement in angular 2 typescript, and where do I hookup this metamask web3 inject so that it will popup the metamask wallet whenever I trigger `web3.eth.sendTransaction()`

Answer (score 5):

The simpliest way to do this is to edit main.ts

and replace

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

by

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

});
```

then create a service and do

```
declare global {
  interface Window { web3: any; }
}

window.web3 = window.web3 || {};

@Injectable()
export class Web3Service {

  web3: any;

  constructor() {
    this.web3 = window.web3;
  }

  getWeb3() {
    return this.web3;
  }
```

Comment: I get this error:
ERROR in src/main.ts(15,21): error TS2339: Property 'web3' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Answer (score 1):

Oraclize's [StackExchange Bounty ÐApp](https://github.com/oraclize/dapp-stackexchange-bounty) might be good to use as an example. It's [deployed](https://dapps.ethercasts.com/dapp/stackexchange-bounty-dapp), but doesn't seem to get much use. It uses an Angular2 front-end. (I'm sure there are lots of others, but this is the only one I've played with.)

Specifically, take a look at how the [`web3.service.ts`](https://github.com/oraclize/dapp-stackexchange-bounty/blob/840045456da569cc30e6a0f823915c1ca521047b/web-ui/dist/tmp/app/shared/web3/web3.service.ts) Typescript file handles MetaMask connections in its `@Injectable` ([line 161](https://github.com/oraclize/dapp-stackexchange-bounty/blob/840045456da569cc30e6a0f823915c1ca521047b/web-ui/dist/tmp/app/shared/web3/web3.service.ts#L161)):

```
connectToNode(): void { // Don't unlock until you send a transaction
    if (typeof window['web3'] !== 'undefined' && (!localStorage['nodeIP'] || this.nodeIP === 'MetaMask')) {
        localStorage['nodeIP'] = this.nodeIP;
        console.log('Using injected web3');
        this.web3 = new this.Web3(window['web3'].currentProvider);
        this.nodeIP = 'MetaMask';
        this.nodeConnected = true;
        this.unlockedAccount = 'MetaMask';
        this.update.emit(null);
    } else {
        localStorage['nodeIP'] = this.nodeIP;
        console.log('Using HTTP node');
        this.unlockedAccount = undefined;
        this.web3 = new this.Web3(new this.Web3.providers.HttpProvider(this.nodeIP));
        this.handleConnection(this.web3.isConnected());
    }
}
```

You'll have to look at how their whole project is set up to get an idea of services, etc., but it's a good place to start.

Comment: thank you for your hint, the SEBouty Dapp is too old and obsolete with angular2 rc5, i can not install successfully the project. I just need some guid how to use the window object to hook up the MetaMask injected web3 that i saw when the page load, i just need to know how to rewrite above piece of code in typescript